# github angularJS bootstrap tutorial giving errors

Tags: angularjs

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Above is the link for the best tutorial and code i've found for angularJS bootstrap combined elements.

Code for html and angularJS is given for :datepicker,timepicker,typeheads,accordion,lot more...best site to refer.

Now my only problem is that when i tried accordion from that page from where i directly copy pasted the angularJS and html code, it did not seem to work. I tried the typehead and the accordion.

Do I need to download , save and link a some file locally?
i dont seem to get it! anyone who has tried the above can just tell me?

typehead.html:

```
                <head>

      <title>Angular Accordion</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
      <script src="typehead.js"></script>





    </head>

    <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
        <a>
          <img ng-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/{{match.model.flag}}" width="16">
          <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
        </a>
      </script>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="customPopupTemplate.html">
        <div class="custom-popup-wrapper" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block;" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
          <p class="message">select location from drop down.</p>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
            <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
              <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </script>


      <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

        <h4>Static arrays</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

        <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        <div ng-show="noResults">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
        </div>

        <h4>ngModelOptions support</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{ngModelOptionsSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ngModelOptionsSelected" ng-model-options="modelOptions" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

        <h4>Custom templates for results</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{customSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true"
        typeahead-min-length="0">

        <h4>Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown</h4>
        <pre>Model: {{customPopupSelected | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customPopupSelected" placeholder="Custom popup template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in statesWithFlags | filter:{name:$viewValue}" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </body>
```

typehead.js:

```
                 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

     angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

       var _selected;


       $scope.selected = undefined;
       $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
       // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously
       $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
         return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
           params: {
             address: val,
             sensor: false
           }
         }).then(function(response) {
           return response.data.results.map(function(item) {
             return item.formatted_address;
           });
         });
       };

       $scope.ngModelOptionsSelected = function(value) {
         if (arguments.length) {
           _selected = value;
         } else {
           return _selected;
         }
       };

       $scope.modelOptions = {
         debounce: {
           default: 500,
           blur: 250
         },
         getterSetter: true
       };

       $scope.statesWithFlags = [{
         'name': 'Alabama',
         'flag': '5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Alaska',
         'flag': 'e/e6/Flag_of_Alaska.svg/43px-Flag_of_Alaska.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Arizona',
         'flag': '9/9d/Flag_of_Arizona.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arizona.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Arkansas',
         'flag': '9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Arkansas.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'California',
         'flag': '0/01/Flag_of_California.svg/45px-Flag_of_California.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Colorado',
         'flag': '4/46/Flag_of_Colorado.svg/45px-Flag_of_Colorado.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Connecticut',
         'flag': '9/96/Flag_of_Connecticut.svg/39px-Flag_of_Connecticut.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Delaware',
         'flag': 'c/c6/Flag_of_Delaware.svg/45px-Flag_of_Delaware.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Florida',
         'flag': 'f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg/45px-Flag_of_Florida.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Georgia',
         'flag': '5/54/Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg/46px-Flag_of_Georgia_%28U.S._state%29.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Hawaii',
         'flag': 'e/ef/Flag_of_Hawaii.svg/46px-Flag_of_Hawaii.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Idaho',
         'flag': 'a/a4/Flag_of_Idaho.svg/38px-Flag_of_Idaho.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Illinois',
         'flag': '0/01/Flag_of_Illinois.svg/46px-Flag_of_Illinois.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Indiana',
         'flag': 'a/ac/Flag_of_Indiana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Indiana.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Iowa',
         'flag': 'a/aa/Flag_of_Iowa.svg/44px-Flag_of_Iowa.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Kansas',
         'flag': 'd/da/Flag_of_Kansas.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kansas.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Kentucky',
         'flag': '8/8d/Flag_of_Kentucky.svg/46px-Flag_of_Kentucky.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Louisiana',
         'flag': 'e/e0/Flag_of_Louisiana.svg/46px-Flag_of_Louisiana.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Maine',
         'flag': '3/35/Flag_of_Maine.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maine.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Maryland',
         'flag': 'a/a0/Flag_of_Maryland.svg/45px-Flag_of_Maryland.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Massachusetts',
         'flag': 'f/f2/Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg/46px-Flag_of_Massachusetts.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Michigan',
         'flag': 'b/b5/Flag_of_Michigan.svg/45px-Flag_of_Michigan.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Minnesota',
         'flag': 'b/b9/Flag_of_Minnesota.svg/46px-Flag_of_Minnesota.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Mississippi',
         'flag': '4/42/Flag_of_Mississippi.svg/45px-Flag_of_Mississippi.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Missouri',
         'flag': '5/5a/Flag_of_Missouri.svg/46px-Flag_of_Missouri.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Montana',
         'flag': 'c/cb/Flag_of_Montana.svg/45px-Flag_of_Montana.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Nebraska',
         'flag': '4/4d/Flag_of_Nebraska.svg/46px-Flag_of_Nebraska.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Nevada',
         'flag': 'f/f1/Flag_of_Nevada.svg/45px-Flag_of_Nevada.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New Hampshire',
         'flag': '2/28/Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Hampshire.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New Jersey',
         'flag': '9/92/Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Jersey.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New Mexico',
         'flag': 'c/c3/Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg/45px-Flag_of_New_Mexico.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'New York',
         'flag': '1/1a/Flag_of_New_York.svg/46px-Flag_of_New_York.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'North Carolina',
         'flag': 'b/bb/Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_North_Carolina.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'North Dakota',
         'flag': 'e/ee/Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg/38px-Flag_of_North_Dakota.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Ohio',
         'flag': '4/4c/Flag_of_Ohio.svg/46px-Flag_of_Ohio.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Oklahoma',
         'flag': '6/6e/Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg/45px-Flag_of_Oklahoma.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Oregon',
         'flag': 'b/b9/Flag_of_Oregon.svg/46px-Flag_of_Oregon.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Pennsylvania',
         'flag': 'f/f7/Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg/45px-Flag_of_Pennsylvania.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Rhode Island',
         'flag': 'f/f3/Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg/32px-Flag_of_Rhode_Island.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'South Carolina',
         'flag': '6/69/Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg/45px-Flag_of_South_Carolina.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'South Dakota',
         'flag': '1/1a/Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg/46px-Flag_of_South_Dakota.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Tennessee',
         'flag': '9/9e/Flag_of_Tennessee.svg/46px-Flag_of_Tennessee.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Texas',
         'flag': 'f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg/45px-Flag_of_Texas.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Utah',
         'flag': 'f/f6/Flag_of_Utah.svg/45px-Flag_of_Utah.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Vermont',
         'flag': '4/49/Flag_of_Vermont.svg/46px-Flag_of_Vermont.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Virginia',
         'flag': '4/47/Flag_of_Virginia.svg/44px-Flag_of_Virginia.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Washington',
         'flag': '5/54/Flag_of_Washington.svg/46px-Flag_of_Washington.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'West Virginia',
         'flag': '2/22/Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg/46px-Flag_of_West_Virginia.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Wisconsin',
         'flag': '2/22/Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg/45px-Flag_of_Wisconsin.svg.png'
       }, {
         'name': 'Wyoming',
         'flag': 'b/bc/Flag_of_Wyoming.svg/43px-Flag_of_Wyoming.svg.png'
       }];
     });
```

above is the exact code i copy pasted from the documentation but failed to get the result!

Following was the error shown by the console:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <            (index):1
```

Console error 2 after adding correct links from user response 'shankar Gurav':

```
        Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.demo due to:
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap.demo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap.demo
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:68:12
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:2015:17
            at ensure (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:1939:38)
            at module (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:2013:14)
            at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4503:22
            at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:321:20)
            at loadModules (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4487:5)
            at createInjector (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:4409:19)
            at doBootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:1691:20)
            at bootstrap (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js:1712:12)
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap.demo&p….googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.0%2Fangular.js%3A1712%3A12)
```

Comment: You Should Put all these code in a Plunker and .. This is a Loong Post

Comment: check if you have included all the necessary files and that they are present in the specified locations

Comment: just change `'ui.bootstrap.demo'` to `'ui.bootstrap'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could do it this way**

**In HTML File add it like this :**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp"></html>

OR

<body ng-app="myApp"></body>
```

**But Adding in HTML tag would considered best practice instead of body tag unless you don't have more than module**

**In Controller File Add following Code**

```
var myApp= angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
//your code 
});
```

Comment: no! still not working! i shalll start from scratch again!

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this:

```
var demo = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

demo.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
//your code 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting injector error.. so 1st check if your files are in your directory, 2nd check your linking and even if your getting the same error then check your spelling mistakes (sometimes these errors are just occurs because of some silly mistake).

make sure u have your "ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js" (or minified file) file in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

just change `'ui.bootstrap.demo'` to `'ui.bootstrap'`